# HTML Agility Pack parsing long url with params in src attributes for images

Tags: html, html-agility-pack

I faced a problem with src attribute for images when parsing a html doc using HAP. Id the src attribute value is a long url with parameter, example: `<img border='0' title='Kommunelogo' alt='Kommunelogo' style='margin-top: 5px;' src='http://livskraftig.bedrekommune.no/more/reports/profilechart.jsp?legend=Y&graphtype=xy&profileid=19433213274429306&element=72&addyears=true' />`

then the HAP parses the image like this: `<img border='0' title='Kommunelogo' alt='Kommunelogo' style='margin-top: 5px;' src='http://livskraftig.bedrekommune.no/more/reports/profilechart.jsp?legend="Y"&amp;amp;graphtype="xy"&amp;amp;profileid="19433213274429306"&amp;amp;element="72"&amp;amp;addyears="tru"e'/>`

It looks like HAP splits the params thinking they are attributes.

My code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.OptionOutputAsXml = true;
doc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true;
doc.OptionFixNestedTags = true;
doc.LoadHtml(input_which_is_a_whole_html_file);

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection imageNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img");
if (imageNodes != null)
{
    foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode imgNode in imageNodes)
    {
        string imgSrc = imgNode.Attributes["src"].Value;
    }
}
```

Any ideas how can i avoid this ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you provide us the entire document you're trying to parse? Testing your code in a document with only that 'img', the HAP returns the url perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably doing something strange, because the following works fine:

```
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml("<img border='0' title='Kommunelogo' alt='Kommunelogo' style='margin-top: 5px;' src='http://livskraftig.bedrekommune.no/more/reports/profilechart.jsp?legend=Y&graphtype=xy&profileid=19433213274429306&element=72&addyears=true' />");
    doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

Do you have a repro?